# What's the VHDL equivalent of verilog 2001's “+:” operator?

Tags: vhdl

In Verilog 2001 and SystemVerilog I can slice a logic vector up using "+:" operator as follows:

```
module testit;

    reg [31:0] avec;
    reg [7:0]  a0, a1, a2;

    initial begin
        avec = 32'hABCD1234;

        a0 = avec[0*8 +: 8];  //same as: a0 = avec[7:0]
        a1 = avec[1*8 +: 8];  //same as: a1 = avec[15:8]
        a2 = avec[2*8 +: 8];  //same as: a2 = avec[23:16]
    end 

endmodule
```

Does VHDL has a similar function in standard IEEE or other package? 
or is there a way to implement this feature as a VHDL function?

Comment: Values produced by *slice names* are *basic operations*. IEEE Std 1076-2008 5. Types 5.1 General, 8. Names 8.5 Slice names 5.3.2.2 Index constraints and discrete ranges.

Comment: See 9. Expressions 9.2 Operators for VHDL's operators which can be overloaded, but not supplemented, which means a "+:" is out as an operator. Non operator overload providing function declarations have *identifier* designators, 4.2 Subprogram declarations 4.2.1 General 15. Lexical elements 15.4 Identifiers. The term *feature* isn't defined in the standard other than as a reserved word in 24.1.2.24 Protect license directives, 15.10 Reserved words. Notice it isn't a reserved word in VHDL.

Comment: Function calls are expressions while procedure calls are statements, 4. Subprograms and packages 4.1 General.  A procedure slice with two input parameters (an array value and a part select size) could assign one or more output parameters, here e.g. `slice(avec, 8, a0, a1, a2);` where three output parameters are assigned in the procedure subprogram body. Otherwise provide subtypes directly, e.g. a0 <= avec(BYTE0); a1 <= avec(BYTE1); a2 <= avec(BYTE2);` and the three subtypes provide static discrete ranges that must be compatible with the declarations of `avec`, 6.3 Subtype declarations.

Comment: `avec[0*8 +: 8];` <=> `avec[7:0]`??? When would I need this? Why do you want to make simple things cryptic when it doesn't even save typing?

Comment: @mfro I would say it's good programming practice: yes, you could write `[7:0]`, but then it wouldn't line up with the other three lines, which (a) obscures the intent somewhat and (b) might hide a bug.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a bit of an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). The Verilog `:+` (or `-:`) operator is a bit of a hack to get round the fact that this kind of thing:

```
S(some_variable to some_other_variable)
```

is legal in VHDL, but this:

```
S[some_variable:some_other_variable]
```

is illegal in Verilog. Generally, you want to do something more like this:

```
S[some_variable:some_variable-7]
```

but this is also illegal in Verilog. But you can, as you know, do this:

```
S[some_variable-:8]
```

instead. So, in VHDL, you don't need a `+:` (or `-:`) operator, you can just do something like this:

```
S(some_variable downto some_variable-7)
```

Comment: This seems to be a bit of a comment and not an answer. Your first snippet some_variable in the slice name range constraint  can actually be a simple expression.